# Using UISearchController to search TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I know that Apple deprecated the old Search Display Controller. I have a table with data, and I'm simply making a search bar that will allow the user to search for data (this data only contains alphabetical names) from the table view with a search bar. I was trying to use the following code at one point to detect if the user is typing something:

```
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

But I cannot because Apple has deprecated the old way. I understand that I have to use the UISearchController now, and I've looked at Apple's documentation and the sample code they provide, but I have not been able to understand it. I've looked everywhere, but have found no solid examples/tutorials on how to do this with objective-c. Can anyone please explain how we use the tableview in conjunction with the UISearchController in order to allow the user to search the data?

Comment: [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) has many examples to implement `UISearchController` using both Obj-C and Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple demo project [here](https://github.com/wenchenhuang/SearchTableviewDemo)

You need a TableviewController to show data,and a TableviewController to show searchResult

For example,(Code from demo project in the link)

Declare a `SearchResultViewController`

```
@interface SearchResultViewController : UITableViewController
```

Then in main tableview

```
@interface SearchTableViewController()<UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating>
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray * dataArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic)UISearchController * searchcontroller;
@property (strong,nonatomic)SearchResultViewController * resultViewController;
@end
```

In viewDidLoad,setup everything

```
self.resultViewController = [[SearchResultViewController alloc] init];
self.searchcontroller = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultViewController];
self.searchcontroller.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.resultViewController.tableView.delegate = self;
[self.searchcontroller.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchcontroller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchcontroller.searchBar;
```

Then in delegate method,do real search and update searchResultViewController

```
#pragma mark - search bar delegate
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
#pragma mark - UISearchResultUpdating
//Do real search,this is up to you
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    NSString * searchtext = searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSArray * searchResults = [self.dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        BOOL result = NO;
        if ([(NSString *)evaluatedObject hasPrefix:searchtext]) {
            result = YES;
        }
        return result;
    }]];
    SearchResultViewController *tableController = (SearchResultViewController *)self.searchcontroller.searchResultsController;
    tableController.dataArray = searchResults;
    [tableController.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: And when do I call this class? My table view is in my ViewController.m

Comment: You simple need to use searchBar that searchController provide,then you can get action in delegate method. Then change the searchResultController.That is the logic